# Sencha Touch 2.x clicking on button but moving pointer before releasing mouse button doesn't work

Tags: events, button, click, sencha-touch, drag

I hadn't really seen this as a problem until my client mentioned that the majority of his clicks on buttons on the app I'm developing do nothing. I enquired a little about what exactly he was doing and it turns out that he was clicking (using a mouse, this is a sencha touch app that is embedded inside of a windows application and will ultimately be running on a windows 7 UMPC 'tablet') on a button and releasing BUT the pointer had moved between the click and the release (by a couple of pixels). However this seems to not trigger the tap handler for the button. The only way it works is if you click and release in the exact same spot with no dragging inside of the button at all.

I think thats a little odd - clicking and moving the pointer and then releasing, all while still inside of the button - should trigger the event handler IMO. Clicking, moving and releasing OUTSIDE of the button shouldn't (which it does, as expected).

Anyone else experience this or know of a way to counteract this behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this only happens when the app is hosted within WebKit.NET browser control - if I just run it within Chrome the click behaviour is fine - can click and move the mouse and release (while inside the button) and the onTap event fires fine.